# Using reference as template type

Tags: c++

In the following example, `Foo` is not doing what is intended, but I can't figure out why this is allowed to compile.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::string& T;

T Foo(int & i)
{
    return T(i);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    std::string & s = Foo(a);
}
```

I discovered this with templates, but the `typedef` shows that its unrelated to templates.  Needless to say, `s` is not a valid string here.  I would think that constructing the value in the return of `Foo` would produce a compile error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Not terribly shocking your specialization isn't called if you're invoking `Foo<std::string&>(a);` and expecting the specialization `Foo<std::string>()` to be fired.

Comment: @WhozCraig I agree, I was desperate because it wasn't making sense.

Comment: It does, of course, fire, if you directly invoke `Foo<std::string>()`, but that isn't really what you're ultimately looking for, no doubt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, it worth nothing that the problem actually has no relationship to templates because this code compiles a well:

```
typedef std::string& T;
T Foo(int& i) {
    return T(i);
}
```

The reason I *think* this compiles is that the `return` statement is equivalent to

```
return reinterpret_cast<T>(i);
```

in case `T` happens to be a reference members. ... and this, of course, compiles: You promised you knew what you were doing and asked the compiler kindly to believe you.

OK, found it at 5.2.3 [expr.type.conv] paragraph 1:

> ... If the expression list is a single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast expression (5.4). ...

... and 5.4 [expr.cast] paragraph 4:

> The conversions performed by [other forms of casts] a reinterpret_cast (5.2.10) [...] can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion. [...]

(the elisions cover cases involving user defined type, built-in type conversions, `const` conversions, etc.)

Comment: Can you expand on *why* `reinterpret_cast` is called in this case when T is a reference?

Comment: Wow, that is subtle, especially when using templates.  I see a follow up question about prohibiting a reference type for `T` in this case...

Comment: see the end of my answer for how to prohibit it

Comment: @JaredC: Yes, it is subtle and would catch me out as well! I shall create a check for my checker identifying the reference casts. Of course, prohibiting reference types for `T` can either be done using `static_assert()` or `std::enabl_if<...>` together with `std::is_reference<T>`. ... or Jonathan's better suggestion of using curlies! ;)

Comment: or use `T{i}` which is always initialization not a cast

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with templates, you get the same result if `T` is just a typedef for `std::string&` rather than a deduced template parameter:

```
#include <string>

typedef std::string& T;

T Foo(int & i)
{
    return T(i);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    std::string & s = Foo(a);
}
```

Dietmar's answer made me realise this can be further simplified to:

```
#include <string>

typedef std::string& T;

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    std::string & s = T(a);
}
```

where `T(a)` is the same as the cast `(T)a` i.e. `(std::string&)a` which (according to the rules of 5.4 [expr.cast]) will do a `const_cast` if that's valid (which it isn't) or a `static_cast` if that's valid (which it isn't) or a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast` if that's valid (which it isn't) or a `reinterpret_cast` if that's valid (which it **is**) or a `reinterpret_cast` followed by a `const_cast` if that's valid, otherwise the expression is ill-formed.

So as Dietmar said, it's the same as doing a `reinterpret_cast`, i.e.

```
std::string & s = reinterpret_cast<std::string&>(a);
```

I find it quite surprising that the original code compiles, but as it's the same as that line above, it's allowed to compile. Using the result of the cast is undefined behaviour though.

To avoid the surprise where `T(a)` is equivalent to a cast, use the new C++11 uniform initialization syntax, `T{a}`, which is always an initialization, not a cast expression.

Great question, investigating and answering it showed me a new gotcha I wasn't previously aware of, thanks to JaredC and Dietmar for the new piece of knowledge!

Comment: Is it appropriate to edit the question to remote the templates (since 2 people have commented that so far)?  Or should I just leave as-is?

Comment: I think it's OK to edit it ... the question is interesting so it makes sense to clarify it to remove the red herring regarding templates.

Comment: @JaredC: I'd agree with Jonathan. Of course, it would also mean that the answers are being edited to take the changed question into account ;)